# R: regex - Help matching Regex

Tags: regex, r

I'm using this regex:

```
b <-   gsub("^http.*jpg$", "", a)
```

To get ride off this line: "http(whatever).jpg"

But it is not working. Any hint is welcome.

This is my string "a":

```
http://media.linio.com.pe/p/hp-1987-043329-sprite.jpgHPHP-DesktopAll-in-OneIntelCeleron18.5''500GB4GB-...S/.1,399.00S/.1,099.00-21%http://media.linio.com.pe/p/hp-7585-499619-sprite.jpgHPHP-DesktopAllInOne205G1AMDDual-CoreE1-250018.5...S/.1,499.00S/.1,099.00-26%http://media.linio.com.pe/p/intel-8786-003309-sprite.jpgIntelIntel-ComputadoraCorei544604taGeneraciónLEDHP1...S/.1,990.00S/.1,699.00-14%http://media.linio.com.pe/p/neff-8502-46539-sprite.jpgNeffNeff-MochilaUnisexScholar-Amarillo,NegroyBlancoS/.229.90S/.79.90-65%http://media.linio.com.pe/p/halion-3051-744329-sprite.jpgHalionIntel-ComputadoraDualCore1.7Ghz750GB2GB+Led19''...S/.1,499.00S/.1,299.00-13%IntelIntel-CPUCompletoCorei54taGeneracion4GBDDR3500G...S/.1,701.00S/.1,499.99-11%http://media.linio.com.pe/p/hp-5264-7511711-sprite.jpgHPHP-DesktopAll-in-OneIntelDualCore18.5''500GB4GB...S/.1,299.00S/.1,290.00-0%http://media.linio.com.pe/p/amd-1909-183119-sprite.jpgAMDAmd-ComputadoraA10780012Núcleos320GB4GB-NegroS/.1,800.00http://media.linio.com.pe/p/neff-9658-55539-sprite.jpgNeffNeff-MochilaUnisexDaily-AmarilloyCelesteS/.149.90S/.45.00-69%http://media.linio.com.pe/p/amd-5625-212409-sprite.jpgAMDAmd-ComputadoraDualCore4GB+MonitorLedHP+Teclad...S/.1,350.00S/.1,050.00-22%http://media.linio.com.pe/p/amd-8027-952409-sprite.jpgAMDAmd-ComputadoraA107850K4.0Ghz.12NúcleosdeProce...S/.2,200.00S/.1,779.00-19%http://media.linio.com.pe/p/amd-8208-462409-sprite.jpgAMDAmd-ComputadoraA107700K3.8Ghz.10NúcleosdeProce...S/.2,000.00S/.1,559.00-22%
```

Desired output:

```
HPHP-DesktopAll-in-OneIntelCeleron18.5''500GB4GB-...S/.1,399.00S/.1,099.00-21%HPHP-DesktopAllInOne205G1AMDDual-CoreE1-250018.5...S/.1,499.00S/.1,099.00-26%IntelIntel-ComputadoraCorei544604taGeneraciónLEDHP1...S/.1,990.00S/.1,699.00-14%NeffNeff-MochilaUnisexScholar-Amarillo,NegroyBlancoS/.229.90S/.79.90-65%HalionIntel-ComputadoraDualCore1.7Ghz750GB2GB+Led19''...S/.1,499.00S/.1,299.00-13%IntelIntel-CPUCompletoCorei54taGeneracion4GBDDR3500G...S/.1,701.00S/.1,499.99-11%HPHP-DesktopAll-in-OneIntelDualCore18.5''500GB4GB...S/.1,299.00S/.1,290.00-0%AMDAmd-ComputadoraA10780012Núcleos320GB4GB-NegroS/.1,800.00NeffNeff-MochilaUnisexDaily-AmarilloyCelesteS/.149.90S/.45.00-69%AMDAmd-ComputadoraDualCore4GB+MonitorLedHP+Teclad...S/.1,350.00S/.1,050.00-22%AMDAmd-ComputadoraA107850K4.0Ghz.12NúcleosdeProce...S/.2,200.00S/.1,779.00-19%AMDAmd-ComputadoraA107700K3.8Ghz.10NúcleosdeProce...S/.2,000.00S/.1,559.00-22%
```

Comment: What's the desired output? Your sample string  doesn't end in "jpg" so there's no match.

Comment: Get rid of the position anchors (`^` and `$`) and it should do what you want.

Comment: @MrFlick, i've added some desired output. Is the same strings, but without the links starting with http and ending with: .jpg.

Comment: @AlexA. No, there are some links starting with http and ending with jpg in between.  So this wouldn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to want a non-greedy, un-anchored expression. Use

```
b <- gsub("http.*?jpg", "", a)
```

to get the output you desire.

Comment: Thanks, @MrFlick. May you explain the difference between my code and yours?  "^http.*jpg$"

Comment: My code is un-anchored (does't have `^` or `$`) and non-greedy (`.*?` vs `.*` matches smallest part possible). There are terms you should be familiar with if you are going to use regular expression. Try googling them.

Answer (score 0):

The problem most probably is that the regex pattern ends in `jpg$`, where the $ marks the end of the string.
However, your text doesn't end in `jpg`, so there is no match, and thus no replacement.

As outlined in the comments, if you remove the indicators of the string beginning `^` and end `$` gsub should replace all the matches.

EDIT: sorry from your updated expected output you need a non-greedy regex pattern. It will match as soon as possible (i.e. on the smallest possible string, or here on the first closing `jpg`), instead of trying to match the longest one possible.

Here are some [examples using gsub](http://www.endmemo.com/program/R/gsub.php).

Comment: Well i see your point. It won't work because it is one string, not ending with "jpg". I would like to take this into 2 steps:

1) Divide the string in multiple parts... one being the "http... jpg".

2) Replace this "http...jpg" with "". 

Any help in that. Thanks

Comment: the answer above by MrFlick is the correct answer. please accept it if you agree :)